# Exact steps to setup remote debugging for a PC not in my current domain?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

What are exact steps to setup remote debugging for a PC, that is not in my current domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sums up installing, configuring and starting.
First section is step by step to install remote debugging.

[MSDN Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx)